# init is not the designated initializer for instances of ASCollectionNode issue?

Tags: ios, swift

i am facing "init is not the designated initializer for instances of ASCollectionNode" issue in asyncdisplaykit framework

Comment: What is your desired/expected outcome? How should the SO community members help you to a solution for the problem?

Comment: Thanks michael Fourre for responding. when i am initialising method app is crashing with the above issue.

Answer (score 0):

It's because you called `ASCollectionNode()` and it doesn't have an `init()`.

You can call it like this instead:

```
var collectionNode = ASCollectionNode(collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout())
```